# Using Unicode in Oracle and PHP

Tags: php, oracle, unicode

I am currently making a web application, I want to add Unicode support in my application. My application is a search based application. I store some keyword and some text in my database,  and show the result according to keyword in a search query.

I am using Oracle 10g XE edition and PHP 5.

I know nothing about adding Unicode.

Comment: Is it really urgent? Cause it seems a lot of people say their questions are urgent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, have you downloaded a version of XE which supports UNICODE?  Not all of them do.  Check out the [XE Download page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/htdocs/102xewinsoft.html).

OTN has a white paper on Unicode in the database.  It's a few years old now, but it still covers the ground.  [Read it now.](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/globalization/pdf/TWP_AppDev_Unicode_10gR2.pdf)  If you need detailed information regarding  implementation read the [Oracle Globalization Reference](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/toc.htm).

Finally, no overview of Unicode would be complete without a link to Joel's article ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: The linked-to page is about unicode support in php 6, which is still under development.

Comment: Fair point, the OP does specify PHP 5.  I have removed the link.

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't aware of charsets; Its strings are byte-arrays. This means that if you want to handle unicode strings, you will have to deal with encodings manually. The most common solution is to use utf-8 encoded strings both internally and externally. Without knowing for sure, I'd expect that Oracle can communicate in utf-8?

Generally, if you don't know the difference between bytes, characters, encodings and charsets, you'll probably get burned.